# GAS Assembly IDE SASM installation on Ubuntu

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I would be very thankful if someone could help me with the installation of SASM on Ubuntu. SASM is the Assembly IDE and it is available for Fedora and Linux Mint. I was wondering whether it could be installed on Ubuntu or my only solution is to install the Windows version (or to install Linux Mint).

Comment: You can [download packages](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Dman95/xUbuntu_15.10/) and I hope you know how to install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build SASM from source on Ubuntu. Follow the directions given on the git repo (https://github.com/Dman95/SASM).

Comment: Or just use the prebuilt packages ;)